# Select though M2M relationships

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have many-to-many relationship like this:

```
Movie — MovieActor — Actor
id      id           id
        role         name
        movie_id     modified_at
        actor_id
        modified_at
```

Both MovieActor *and* Actor have independent `modified_at` timestamp fields.

How do I select all movies that have either
`MovieActor.modified_at` OR `MovieActor.Actor.modified_at` > some date?

My naive approach is to UNION two queries:

```
(
  SELECT 
    m.id 
  FROM 
    Movie m 
    LEFT JOIN MovieActor ma ON m.id = ma.movie_id 
  WHERE 
    ma.modified_at > some_timestamp
) 
UNION ALL 
  (
    SELECT 
      ma.movie_id 
    FROM 
      Actor a 
      LEFT JOIN MovieActor ma ON ma.actor_id = a.id 
    WHERE 
      a.modified_at > some_timestamp
  )
```

This looks ugly, I guess there should be a better way, please help me find it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an OR condition:

```
SELECT m.id 
FROM Movie m 
  JOIN MovieActor ma ON m.id = ma.movie_id 
  JOIN actor a on a.id = ma.actor_id
WHERE ma.modified_at > some_timestamp
   OR a.modified_at > some_timestamp;
```

Comment: You're filtering movies by MovieActor and **Movie**'s dates, but I need to filter movies by MovieActor and **Actor**'s

Comment: @bizzz: sorry, added the join to `actor`